# What are options for a nested case-type structure in a table join in TSQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join, nested

I need to a join on two conditions - the first is straightforward but the second seems to be asking for a nested case statement but I have been unable to figure out how to make it work or a better option.

The problem is that I have an activity that can happen either once or twice per day.  If it happens once per day I can just join on the date.  If it happens twice a day I need to join from table X to table Y appropriately depending on whether it is morning or afternoon and in doing so I need to basically round a bunch of times from morning and afternoon to a single value for each for the join.

This works great:

```
Inner join table x on x.ser = y.ser and (case when X <= 12 then 9 else 
15) = (case when Y <= 12 then 9 else 15)
```

But if I add another case statement around the original it falls apart and seems like crap code anyway so I figure there must be a better way to solve this but it escapes me.

```
case when (code = BID) then 
(case when X <= 12 then 9 else 15) = (case when Y <= 12 then 9 else 15)
else X = Y
```

Actual non-working code is below.

```
    INNER JOIN dbo.Image img on img.Ser = sa.Ser and 
        case when (ac.ActivityCode = 'BID') then    
            CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour, img.CreationDate) <= 12 THEN 
                 DATEADD(hh, 9, DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, 
                 img.CreationDate), 0)) ELSE DATEADD(hh, 15, DATEADD(dd, 
                 DATEDIFF(dd, 0, img.CreationDate), 0))  
            END = CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour, sa.ActualStartDate) <= 12 THEN 
                       DATEADD(hh, 9, DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, 
                        sa.ActualStartDate), 0)) ELSE DATEADD(hh, 15, 
                        DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, sa.ActualStartDate), 
                        0)) 
                    END 
          ELSE  sa.ActualStartDate = img.CreationDate
        END
```

Comment: have you tried to divide the query into 2 queries (one for the single activity and the other for the multiple activities) ? if not, try to divide them first, get the correct results for both queries, then review them both and tweak them as much as you can, then see what you can do to merge them both in a single query.

Comment: Your suggestion is exactly where I have ended up going.  I figured, as you advise, that it's easier to get to where I want to go that way.  One other thing came up as well -- the user told me that my approach would yield the correct answer 99% of the time but there were a very small number of edge cases where it would not work thus the way you suggest is going to be needed anyway.

Comment: if divided, you can cover all possible cases much easier and faster, although, sometimes it would be necessary to use separate query for each case.So, it's not always a one query solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a comparison statement `{expression 1} = {expression 2}` within a `CASE` statement.

It should be something like

```
INNER JOIN dbo.Image img  on  img.Ser = sa.Ser 
                         and  CASE ... END = CASE ... END
```

But than your query will be hard to read. Why not use a `CTE`. And compute the new expression inside the `CTE`

```
; WITH
CTE1 AS 
( 
    Col2 = CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour, img.CreationDate) <= 12 .....
),
CTE2 AS 
( 
    Col2 = CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour, sa.ActualStartDate) <= 12 .....
)
SELECT *
FROM   CTE1 c1 
JOIN   CTE2 c2  ON c1.Ser  = c2.Ser
               AND c2.Col2 = c2.Col2
```